# delete event trigger something in CGridView of Yii

Tags: yii, cgridview

I merge create and admin views and method in my controller,
so in `admin.php` I have following lines:

```
echo $this->renderPartial('_form',  array('model'=>$create));
echo $this->renderPartial('_admin',  array('model'=>$search));
```

and in _form I edit submit button to

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Submit', Yii::app()->createUrl('money/income'), array('update' => '#money-grid'));
```

and in `money` controller,`income` method implement create method and send  `CGridView` as ajax response.

```
if ($createModel->save()) {
                $this->renderPartial('_admin', array('model' => $searchModel), false, true);
```

if data saved into database,it render `_admin` view which contain `CGridView`,this works prefect ,but problem exist, if client create something and insert into database, so after it click on `delete` of CGridView it will trigger more than one and it makes problem,
for example if user insert **n** rows ,then click on the each row to delete,it will trigger **n + 1** times.(but it should be 1)

where is the problem?is it for Yii?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by updating CGridView by jQuery instead of rendering it,so I changed my ajaxSubmitButton to

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Submit', Yii::app()->createUrl('money/income'), array('success'=>'$.fn.yiiGridView.update("money-grid")'));
```

and it solved problem.

```
'success'=>'$.fn.yiiGridView.update("money-grid")'
```